How to get the same CRC32 like cksum?
I took the source code of cksum and copied the polynomial. This gives the same as the predefined IEEE variant defined in the Go standard library.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "hash/crc32"
)

// https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/a9b78541fa7c06567c5b82fb4e89d85a1dc0c611/src/cksum.c#L54
//
//          32   26   23   22   16   12   11   10   8   7   5   4   2   1
//    G(X)=X  + X  + X  + X  + X  + X  + X  + X  + X + X + X + X + X + X + 1

const p = 0b11101101101110001000001100100000

func main() {
    cksum := crc32.MakeTable(p)
    fmt.Println(crc32.Checksum([]byte("moin"), cksum))
    fmt.Println(crc32.ChecksumIEEE([]byte("moin")))
}

The result is: 3048661102
But when I use the cksum on Debian 12 (coreutils 9.1) the result is something else:
$ printf "moin" | cksum 
1401816862 4

What is wrong here?
Update
I think the problem is explained here.
But the question is still: How to do with "hash/crc32" the same as cksum does?
It does not work even with a hard coded table.

Which one are you trying to "fix" here? From man cksum you want -o 3 to get a "32-bit CRC" to match the Go version.

@JimB Can not find -o: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cksum.1.html

sorry, forgo the old bsd version is probably different. I don't have a linux system handy to test, but there are a few different algorithms you could try.

Check the parameters for CRC-32/CKSUM on
https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm
width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0x00000000 refin=false refout=false xorout=0xffffffff check=0x765e7680 residue=0xc704dd7b name="CRC-32/CKSUM"

And compare with the parameters for CRC-32/ISO-HDLC, which I believe corresponds to the algorithm in hash/crc32:
width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0xffffffff refin=true refout=true xorout=0xffffffff check=0xcbf43926 residue=0xdebb20e3 name="CRC-32/ISO-HDLC"

It is only possible to adjust poly (the polynom) in hash/crc32, but not init (initial value), refin (reflected input) or refout (reflected output).
In addition to these parameters, the cksum program also processes a representation of the input stream length following the input.
Here is some naive code that produces the expected output with hash/crc32. A fast/real implementation would create another table from the polynom.

This is good to know and it answers the question, but unfortunately this is not practical, it is even slower than the OpenGroup reference. https://go.dev/play/p/dpWLmaHRdi-

@ceving https://go.dev/play/p/VtBY4XWcIgS here's a solution that produces a custom table, to avoid reflecting every input byte. It should be faster, but a custom table like this would still not benefit from the architecture specific optimizations.

Reverse table seems to be still slower than OpenGroup.

That one is the CRC-32/CKSUM:
width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0x00000000 refin=false refout=false xorout=0xffffffff check=0x765e7680 residue=0xc704dd7b name="CRC-32/CKSUM"

This CRC shifts up (refin and refout false), whereas the Go hash/crc32 package appears to only support CRC's that shift down (refin and refout true). You would have to write your own CRC code.
Here is an example in C, which you could translate to Go:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint32_t const table_byte[] = {
    0xb1f7404b, 0xb5365dfc, 0xb8757b25, 0xbcb46692, 0xa2f33697, 0xa6322b20,
    0xab710df9, 0xafb0104e, 0x97ffadf3, 0x933eb044, 0x9e7d969d, 0x9abc8b2a,
    0x84fbdb2f, 0x803ac698, 0x8d79e041, 0x89b8fdf6, 0xfde69b3b, 0xf927868c,
    0xf464a055, 0xf0a5bde2, 0xeee2ede7, 0xea23f050, 0xe760d689, 0xe3a1cb3e,
    0xdbee7683, 0xdf2f6b34, 0xd26c4ded, 0xd6ad505a, 0xc8ea005f, 0xcc2b1de8,
    0xc1683b31, 0xc5a92686, 0x29d4f6ab, 0x2d15eb1c, 0x2056cdc5, 0x2497d072,
    0x3ad08077, 0x3e119dc0, 0x3352bb19, 0x3793a6ae, 0x0fdc1b13, 0x0b1d06a4,
    0x065e207d, 0x029f3dca, 0x1cd86dcf, 0x18197078, 0x155a56a1, 0x119b4b16,
    0x65c52ddb, 0x6104306c, 0x6c4716b5, 0x68860b02, 0x76c15b07, 0x720046b0,
    0x7f436069, 0x7b827dde, 0x43cdc063, 0x470cddd4, 0x4a4ffb0d, 0x4e8ee6ba,
    0x50c9b6bf, 0x5408ab08, 0x594b8dd1, 0x5d8a9066, 0x8571303c, 0x81b02d8b,
    0x8cf30b52, 0x883216e5, 0x967546e0, 0x92b45b57, 0x9ff77d8e, 0x9b366039,
    0xa379dd84, 0xa7b8c033, 0xaafbe6ea, 0xae3afb5d, 0xb07dab58, 0xb4bcb6ef,
    0xb9ff9036, 0xbd3e8d81, 0xc960eb4c, 0xcda1f6fb, 0xc0e2d022, 0xc423cd95,
    0xda649d90, 0xdea58027, 0xd3e6a6fe, 0xd727bb49, 0xef6806f4, 0xeba91b43,
    0xe6ea3d9a, 0xe22b202d, 0xfc6c7028, 0xf8ad6d9f, 0xf5ee4b46, 0xf12f56f1,
    0x1d5286dc, 0x19939b6b, 0x14d0bdb2, 0x1011a005, 0x0e56f000, 0x0a97edb7,
    0x07d4cb6e, 0x0315d6d9, 0x3b5a6b64, 0x3f9b76d3, 0x32d8500a, 0x36194dbd,
    0x285e1db8, 0x2c9f000f, 0x21dc26d6, 0x251d3b61, 0x51435dac, 0x5582401b,
    0x58c166c2, 0x5c007b75, 0x42472b70, 0x468636c7, 0x4bc5101e, 0x4f040da9,
    0x774bb014, 0x738aada3, 0x7ec98b7a, 0x7a0896cd, 0x644fc6c8, 0x608edb7f,
    0x6dcdfda6, 0x690ce011, 0xd8fba0a5, 0xdc3abd12, 0xd1799bcb, 0xd5b8867c,
    0xcbffd679, 0xcf3ecbce, 0xc27ded17, 0xc6bcf0a0, 0xfef34d1d, 0xfa3250aa,
    0xf7717673, 0xf3b06bc4, 0xedf73bc1, 0xe9362676, 0xe47500af, 0xe0b41d18,
    0x94ea7bd5, 0x902b6662, 0x9d6840bb, 0x99a95d0c, 0x87ee0d09, 0x832f10be,
    0x8e6c3667, 0x8aad2bd0, 0xb2e2966d, 0xb6238bda, 0xbb60ad03, 0xbfa1b0b4,
    0xa1e6e0b1, 0xa527fd06, 0xa864dbdf, 0xaca5c668, 0x40d81645, 0x44190bf2,
    0x495a2d2b, 0x4d9b309c, 0x53dc6099, 0x571d7d2e, 0x5a5e5bf7, 0x5e9f4640,
    0x66d0fbfd, 0x6211e64a, 0x6f52c093, 0x6b93dd24, 0x75d48d21, 0x71159096,
    0x7c56b64f, 0x7897abf8, 0x0cc9cd35, 0x0808d082, 0x054bf65b, 0x018aebec,
    0x1fcdbbe9, 0x1b0ca65e, 0x164f8087, 0x128e9d30, 0x2ac1208d, 0x2e003d3a,
    0x23431be3, 0x27820654, 0x39c55651, 0x3d044be6, 0x30476d3f, 0x34867088,
    0xec7dd0d2, 0xe8bccd65, 0xe5ffebbc, 0xe13ef60b, 0xff79a60e, 0xfbb8bbb9,
    0xf6fb9d60, 0xf23a80d7, 0xca753d6a, 0xceb420dd, 0xc3f70604, 0xc7361bb3,
    0xd9714bb6, 0xddb05601, 0xd0f370d8, 0xd4326d6f, 0xa06c0ba2, 0xa4ad1615,
    0xa9ee30cc, 0xad2f2d7b, 0xb3687d7e, 0xb7a960c9, 0xbaea4610, 0xbe2b5ba7,
    0x8664e61a, 0x82a5fbad, 0x8fe6dd74, 0x8b27c0c3, 0x956090c6, 0x91a18d71,
    0x9ce2aba8, 0x9823b61f, 0x745e6632, 0x709f7b85, 0x7ddc5d5c, 0x791d40eb,
    0x675a10ee, 0x639b0d59, 0x6ed82b80, 0x6a193637, 0x52568b8a, 0x5697963d,
    0x5bd4b0e4, 0x5f15ad53, 0x4152fd56, 0x4593e0e1, 0x48d0c638, 0x4c11db8f,
    0x384fbd42, 0x3c8ea0f5, 0x31cd862c, 0x350c9b9b, 0x2b4bcb9e, 0x2f8ad629,
    0x22c9f0f0, 0x2608ed47, 0x1e4750fa, 0x1a864d4d, 0x17c56b94, 0x13047623,
    0x0d432626, 0x09823b91, 0x04c11d48, 0x000000ff
};

uint32_t crc32cksum_byte(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    uint8_t const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffffffff;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ table_byte[((crc >> 24) ^ data[i]) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}

The initial CRC value (returned for mem == NULL) is 0xffffffff.
As noted by @LarsChristianJensen, You need to append to the message the length of the message in little-endian order, for just as many bytes as needed to represent the length. (If the length is zero, zero bytes are appended.) The CRC is calculated on the message + the appended length.
You can use crcany to generate the above code, along with code for a faster slice-by-8 implementation. (Stackoverflow answers are limited in length, which prevents me from putting the code in this answer.)

The cksum program also processes a representation of the input stream length following the input, so I think you need to pass "moin\x04" to get the expected result.

I saw the C versions. But the Go module has some architecture specific optimizations. I would like to use them instead of using some new code. I am wondering if it is possible to craft a custom table which works with "hash/crc32".

No. You did not read my answer. It is not possible for hash/crc32 to compute this CRC with modifying the code or flipping the bits in the input bytes (which would negate any speed advantage), since it shifts in the opposite direction.

If you would like a slice-by-8 implementation, see the end of my answer.

This is very similar to the algorithm on the OpenGroup website and has the same performance.

This is my conclusion:

It is impossible to exceed the performance of Go's standard implementation with generic code.
It is impossible to prepare the input to achieve cksum compatibility while still keeping the performance of Go's standard implemenation.

Generic code is more than a magnitude slower than Go's optimized code:
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900X CPU @ 3.70GHz
Benchmark_OpenGroup
Benchmark_OpenGroup-6                      16576         63555 ns/op
Benchmark_HashCrc32ReverseInput
Benchmark_HashCrc32ReverseInput-6          16914         73833 ns/op
Benchmark_HashCrc32ReverseTable
Benchmark_HashCrc32ReverseTable-6          16210         68378 ns/op
Benchmark_Crcany
Benchmark_Crcany-6                         18874         63727 ns/op
Benchmark_HashCRC32Native
Benchmark_HashCRC32Native-6               866377          1392 ns/op
PASS

In the end the alternatives are:

Be slow and compatible to cksum.
Be fast and incompatible to cksum.

Test program:
package cksum

import (
    _ "embed"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "hash/crc32"
    "math/bits"
    "testing"
)

//======================================================================
// Input data

func append_length(bytes []byte) []byte {
    length := []byte{}
    n := len(bytes)
    for n != 0 {
        length = append(length, byte(n&0377))
        n >>= 8
    }
    return append(bytes, length...)
}

//go:generate bash -c "printf moin > moin"
//go:embed moin
var file_moin []byte

//go:generate bash -c "cksum moin > moin.cksum"
//go:embed moin.cksum
var cksum_moin string

//go:generate bash -c "if [ ! -e 40BD0 ]; then wget -q https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/40BD0; fi"
//go:embed 40BD0
var file_40BD0 []byte

//go:generate bash -c "cksum 40BD0 > 40BD0.cksum"
//go:embed 40BD0.cksum
var cksum_40BD0 string

var (
    data_short  []byte
    data_long   []byte
    cksum_short uint32
    cksum_long  uint32
)

func init() {
    data_short = append_length(file_moin)
    data_long = append_length(file_40BD0)

    var err error
    _, err = fmt.Sscanf(cksum_moin, "%d", &cksum_short)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = fmt.Sscanf(cksum_40BD0, "%d", &cksum_long)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

//======================================================================
// Translation of the OpenGroup C reference implementation
//
// https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/cksum.html

var opengroup_crctab = []uint32{
    0x00000000,
    0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b,
    0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005, 0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6,
    0x2b4bcb61, 0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd,
    0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9, 0x5f15adac,
    0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75, 0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f,
    0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3, 0x709f7b7a,
    0x745e66cd, 0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039,
    0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5, 0xbe2b5b58,
    0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033,
    0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d, 0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe,
    0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022, 0xca753d95,
    0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1, 0xe13ef6f4,
    0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d, 0x34867077, 0x30476dc0,
    0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5,
    0x2ac12072, 0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16,
    0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca, 0x7897ab07,
    0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde, 0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c,
    0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02, 0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08, 0x571d7dd1,
    0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
    0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e, 0xbfa1b04b,
    0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692, 0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698,
    0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6, 0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d,
    0x94ea7b2a, 0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e,
    0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2, 0xc6bcf05f,
    0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34,
    0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a, 0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80,
    0x644fc637, 0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb,
    0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f, 0x5c007b8a,
    0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53, 0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629,
    0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5, 0x3f9b762c,
    0x3b5a6b9b, 0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff,
    0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623, 0xf12f560e,
    0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65,
    0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b, 0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8,
    0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3,
    0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7, 0xae3afba2,
    0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b, 0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71,
    0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74,
    0x857130c3, 0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640,
    0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c, 0x7b827d21,
    0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8, 0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a,
    0x61043093, 0x65c52d24, 0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e, 0x18197087,
    0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
    0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088, 0x2497d08d,
    0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654, 0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce,
    0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0, 0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb,
    0xdbee767c, 0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18,
    0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4, 0x89b8fd09,
    0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662,
    0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c, 0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf,
    0xa2f33668, 0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4}

/*
unsigned long memcrc(const unsigned char *b, size_t n)
{
    // Input arguments:
    // const char*   b == byte sequence to checksum
    // size_t        n == length of sequence

    register unsigned   i, c, s = 0;

    for (i = n; i > 0; --i) {
        c = (unsigned)(*b++);
        s = (s << 8) ^ crctab[(s >> 24) ^ c];
    }

    // Extend with the length of the string.
    while (n != 0) {
        c = n & 0377;
        n >>= 8;
        s = (s << 8) ^ crctab[(s >> 24) ^ c];
    }

    return ˜s;
}
*/

func OpenGroup(bytes []byte) uint32 {
    var s uint32
    for _, c := range bytes {
        s = (s << 8) ^ opengroup_crctab[(s>>24)^uint32(c)]
    }
    return ^s
}

//======================================================================
// Implementation using hash/crc32 by reversing input

func HashCrc32ReverseInput(bytes []byte) uint32 {
    input := make([]byte, len(bytes))

    // because refin=false
    for i := range bytes {
        input[i] = bits.Reverse8(bytes[i])
    }

    // because init=0x00000000
    v := crc32.Update(^uint32(0), crc32.IEEETable, input)

    // because refout=false
    v = bits.Reverse32(v)

    return v
}

//======================================================================
// Implementation using hash/crc32 by reversing the table

func reverseEachByte(n uint32) uint32 {
    var buf [4]byte
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(buf[:], n)
    buf[0] = bits.Reverse8(buf[0])
    buf[1] = bits.Reverse8(buf[1])
    buf[2] = bits.Reverse8(buf[2])
    buf[3] = bits.Reverse8(buf[3])
    return binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buf[:])
}

var table crc32.Table

func init() {
    for i, v := range crc32.IEEETable {
        table[bits.Reverse8(uint8(i))] = reverseEachByte(v)
    }
}

func HashCrc32ReverseTable(bytes []byte) uint32 {
    v := crc32.Update(^uint32(0), &table, bytes)
    v = reverseEachByte(v)
    v = bits.Reverse32(v)
    return v
}

//======================================================================
// Translation of the Crcany C implementation

var table_byte = []uint32{
    0xb1f7404b, 0xb5365dfc, 0xb8757b25, 0xbcb46692, 0xa2f33697, 0xa6322b20,
    0xab710df9, 0xafb0104e, 0x97ffadf3, 0x933eb044, 0x9e7d969d, 0x9abc8b2a,
    0x84fbdb2f, 0x803ac698, 0x8d79e041, 0x89b8fdf6, 0xfde69b3b, 0xf927868c,
    0xf464a055, 0xf0a5bde2, 0xeee2ede7, 0xea23f050, 0xe760d689, 0xe3a1cb3e,
    0xdbee7683, 0xdf2f6b34, 0xd26c4ded, 0xd6ad505a, 0xc8ea005f, 0xcc2b1de8,
    0xc1683b31, 0xc5a92686, 0x29d4f6ab, 0x2d15eb1c, 0x2056cdc5, 0x2497d072,
    0x3ad08077, 0x3e119dc0, 0x3352bb19, 0x3793a6ae, 0x0fdc1b13, 0x0b1d06a4,
    0x065e207d, 0x029f3dca, 0x1cd86dcf, 0x18197078, 0x155a56a1, 0x119b4b16,
    0x65c52ddb, 0x6104306c, 0x6c4716b5, 0x68860b02, 0x76c15b07, 0x720046b0,
    0x7f436069, 0x7b827dde, 0x43cdc063, 0x470cddd4, 0x4a4ffb0d, 0x4e8ee6ba,
    0x50c9b6bf, 0x5408ab08, 0x594b8dd1, 0x5d8a9066, 0x8571303c, 0x81b02d8b,
    0x8cf30b52, 0x883216e5, 0x967546e0, 0x92b45b57, 0x9ff77d8e, 0x9b366039,
    0xa379dd84, 0xa7b8c033, 0xaafbe6ea, 0xae3afb5d, 0xb07dab58, 0xb4bcb6ef,
    0xb9ff9036, 0xbd3e8d81, 0xc960eb4c, 0xcda1f6fb, 0xc0e2d022, 0xc423cd95,
    0xda649d90, 0xdea58027, 0xd3e6a6fe, 0xd727bb49, 0xef6806f4, 0xeba91b43,
    0xe6ea3d9a, 0xe22b202d, 0xfc6c7028, 0xf8ad6d9f, 0xf5ee4b46, 0xf12f56f1,
    0x1d5286dc, 0x19939b6b, 0x14d0bdb2, 0x1011a005, 0x0e56f000, 0x0a97edb7,
    0x07d4cb6e, 0x0315d6d9, 0x3b5a6b64, 0x3f9b76d3, 0x32d8500a, 0x36194dbd,
    0x285e1db8, 0x2c9f000f, 0x21dc26d6, 0x251d3b61, 0x51435dac, 0x5582401b,
    0x58c166c2, 0x5c007b75, 0x42472b70, 0x468636c7, 0x4bc5101e, 0x4f040da9,
    0x774bb014, 0x738aada3, 0x7ec98b7a, 0x7a0896cd, 0x644fc6c8, 0x608edb7f,
    0x6dcdfda6, 0x690ce011, 0xd8fba0a5, 0xdc3abd12, 0xd1799bcb, 0xd5b8867c,
    0xcbffd679, 0xcf3ecbce, 0xc27ded17, 0xc6bcf0a0, 0xfef34d1d, 0xfa3250aa,
    0xf7717673, 0xf3b06bc4, 0xedf73bc1, 0xe9362676, 0xe47500af, 0xe0b41d18,
    0x94ea7bd5, 0x902b6662, 0x9d6840bb, 0x99a95d0c, 0x87ee0d09, 0x832f10be,
    0x8e6c3667, 0x8aad2bd0, 0xb2e2966d, 0xb6238bda, 0xbb60ad03, 0xbfa1b0b4,
    0xa1e6e0b1, 0xa527fd06, 0xa864dbdf, 0xaca5c668, 0x40d81645, 0x44190bf2,
    0x495a2d2b, 0x4d9b309c, 0x53dc6099, 0x571d7d2e, 0x5a5e5bf7, 0x5e9f4640,
    0x66d0fbfd, 0x6211e64a, 0x6f52c093, 0x6b93dd24, 0x75d48d21, 0x71159096,
    0x7c56b64f, 0x7897abf8, 0x0cc9cd35, 0x0808d082, 0x054bf65b, 0x018aebec,
    0x1fcdbbe9, 0x1b0ca65e, 0x164f8087, 0x128e9d30, 0x2ac1208d, 0x2e003d3a,
    0x23431be3, 0x27820654, 0x39c55651, 0x3d044be6, 0x30476d3f, 0x34867088,
    0xec7dd0d2, 0xe8bccd65, 0xe5ffebbc, 0xe13ef60b, 0xff79a60e, 0xfbb8bbb9,
    0xf6fb9d60, 0xf23a80d7, 0xca753d6a, 0xceb420dd, 0xc3f70604, 0xc7361bb3,
    0xd9714bb6, 0xddb05601, 0xd0f370d8, 0xd4326d6f, 0xa06c0ba2, 0xa4ad1615,
    0xa9ee30cc, 0xad2f2d7b, 0xb3687d7e, 0xb7a960c9, 0xbaea4610, 0xbe2b5ba7,
    0x8664e61a, 0x82a5fbad, 0x8fe6dd74, 0x8b27c0c3, 0x956090c6, 0x91a18d71,
    0x9ce2aba8, 0x9823b61f, 0x745e6632, 0x709f7b85, 0x7ddc5d5c, 0x791d40eb,
    0x675a10ee, 0x639b0d59, 0x6ed82b80, 0x6a193637, 0x52568b8a, 0x5697963d,
    0x5bd4b0e4, 0x5f15ad53, 0x4152fd56, 0x4593e0e1, 0x48d0c638, 0x4c11db8f,
    0x384fbd42, 0x3c8ea0f5, 0x31cd862c, 0x350c9b9b, 0x2b4bcb9e, 0x2f8ad629,
    0x22c9f0f0, 0x2608ed47, 0x1e4750fa, 0x1a864d4d, 0x17c56b94, 0x13047623,
    0x0d432626, 0x09823b91, 0x04c11d48, 0x000000ff}

/*
uint32_t crc32cksum_byte(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    uint8_t const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffffffff;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ table_byte[((crc >> 24) ^ data[i]) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}
*/

func Crcany(data []byte) uint32 {
    crc := uint32(0xffffffff)
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ table_byte[((crc>>24)^uint32(data[i]))&0xff]
    }
    return crc
}

//======================================================================
// Tests with short input

func Test_OpenGroup_Short(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_short
    reading := OpenGroup(data_short)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

func Test_HashCrc32ReverseInput_Short(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_short
    reading := HashCrc32ReverseInput(data_short)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

func Test_HashCrc32ReverseTable_Short(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_short
    reading := HashCrc32ReverseTable(data_short)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

func Test_Crcany_Short(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_short
    reading := Crcany(data_short)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

//======================================================================
// Tests with long input

func Test_Opengroup_Long(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_long
    reading := OpenGroup(data_long)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

func Test_HashCrc32ReverseInput_Long(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_long
    reading := HashCrc32ReverseInput(data_long)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

func Test_HashCrc32ReverseTable_Long(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_long
    reading := HashCrc32ReverseTable(data_long)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

func Test_Crcany_Long(t *testing.T) {
    setpoint := cksum_long
    reading := Crcany(data_long)
    if reading != setpoint {
        t.Fatalf(`Wrong cksum: setpoint=%v reading=%v`, setpoint, reading)
    }
}

//======================================================================
// Benchmarks

func Benchmark_OpenGroup(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = OpenGroup(data_long)
    }
}

func Benchmark_HashCrc32ReverseInput(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = HashCrc32ReverseInput(data_long)
    }
}

func Benchmark_HashCrc32ReverseTable(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = HashCrc32ReverseTable(data_long)
    }
}

func Benchmark_Crcany(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = Crcany(data_long)
    }
}

func Benchmark_HashCRC32Native(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        _ = crc32.ChecksumIEEE(data_long)
    }
}

// Local Variables:
// compile-command: "go test -v -bench=. cksum_test.go"
// End:


You never asked anywhere in your question "with the same performance". You are answering a question you did not ask.

To get the same performance on your particular architecture (amd64), you would need to rewrite this assembler code for the cksum CRC, which can be done: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.2:src/hash/crc32/crc32_amd64.s It uses the PCLMULQDQ hardware instruction.

You did not try slice-by-8 from crcany. It's performance would fall between the usual byte-wise code and the hardware-instruction code.

@MarkAdler Yes, I was a bit naive when I asked the question. Little did I know that choosing the implementation would increase the runtime of my program from one day to three weeks. I also didn't know that implementing it myself would increase the development time of my program from 15 minutes to a month. The cksum program is a POSIX standard and is therefore worth being compatible with. But I don't want to accept a significant increase in runtime or development time. And the observed increases are significant. And if I give up the compatibility I can use Castagnoli which is even faster.
